# Combine anonymous columns to form new collection

Tags: c#, linq

I’ve been reviewing many, many postings/responses here but haven’t found (or perhaps understood is better description) a solution. I’m trying to develop a linq statement(s) so that I can parse collections of data.

I have an anonymous collection of data where I need to be able to specify two unrelated columns and combine their values to form a new collection of their combined value. The collection is read into an IEnumerable> (and the result needs to the same).

Depending upon the data sample, the columns to be combined will vary. In scenario A (see data sample #1) columns 1 & 3 are needing to be combined to generate a result set (see result #1). In scenario B (see data sample #2) columns 2 & 4 are needing to be combined to generate a result set (see result #2). Column headings (first row) aren’t known ahead of time, and all values are strings (empty string and non-null).

What I would love to see something along the lines of the following:

```
int ColyY = 1;
int ColyX = 3;
var result = FetchMergedColumn(ColX, ColY);
```

**Data sample #1:**

```
Col1       Col2     Col3    Col4
Fish       Blue     Cloudy  10
Dog        Red      Rain    33
Cat        Black    Thunder 55
```

**Result #1:**

```
Fish    Cloudy
Dog     Rain
Cat     Thunder
```

**Data sample #2:**

```
Col1      Col2      Col3    Col4
Blue      Fish      10      Cloudy
Red       Dog       33      Rain
Black     Cat       55      Thunder
```

**Result #2:**

```
Fish    Cloudy
Dog     Rain
Cat     Thunder
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: How does the collection look like? Is it really a `IEnumerable<T>`, where `T` is an anonymous type? Because that doesn't make much sense. What should be the type of `result`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by ``column``? You said you have a anonymous collection of data. Are these 'columns' properties of the anonymous type that makes up the collection?

Comment: Based on the comments and @svick's comment on my answer, I think we need some clarification on the form of your sample data...

Comment: The data is read from a file; CSV to be exact. I read the data in, construct a List<List<string>> and it. It's at that point I want to be able to selectively choose which columns to merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this quite easily using LINQ:

```
List<List<string>> SelectColumns(List<List<string>> data, params int[] columns)
{
    return data.Select(row => row.Where((_, i) => columns.Contains(i))
                                 .ToList())
               .ToList();
}
```

This assumes you want to return back `List<List<string>>` again. Also, it uses zero-based indexing, so, to get your Result #1, you would call it like this:

```
var result = SelectColumns(source, 0, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind that 1. this has no argument checking or error handling, and 2. I haven't actually run it to see if it does exactly what you want, how about something like this?

```
public static string[][] FetchMergedColumns(params int[] columnNumbers)
{
    var dataSample = new[]
    {
        new[] { "Fish", "Dog", "Cat" },
        new[] { "Blue", "Red", "Black" },
        new[] { "Cloudy", "Rain", "Thunder" },
        new[] { "10", "33", "55" }
    };

    return columnNumbers
        .Select(colNum => dataSample.ElementAt(colNum - 1))
        .ToArray();
}
```

Obviously you wouldn't define the data sample in the method, but hopefully this may point you in the right direction.

Comment: As I understand the question, the data elements are more like `{ "Fish", "Blue", "Cloudy", "10" }` and the results should probably look that way too.